# LSI MegaRAID: How to convert between Dedicated Hot Space (DHS) to Global Hot Spare (GHS)?

Tags: lsi, megaraid

To see your drives, use `storcli /c0 show all` or `storcli /c0/eXXX/sALL show` (replace `XXX` with the enclosure ID or EID). In my case, the output looks like this:

```
Drive Information :
=================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                Sp Type 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0    10 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0 U  -    
252:1     9 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0 U  -    
252:2    11 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:3     8 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:4    12 Onln   - 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:6    14 GHS    - 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:7    13 GHS    - 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I convert `GHS` to `DHS` or the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`storcli` won't let you change the state of the disk as long as it is "allocated" as hot spare. To deallocate the drive, you need to "delete" it:

```
storcli /c0/e252/s7 delete hotsparedrive
```

This will make the disk 13 (in Slot 7) attached to enclosure 252 connected to controller 0 available:

```
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                Sp Type 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:7    13 UGood  - 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -
```

The state is now "UGood". That means you can add the disk to an existing array or convert it to a dedicated/global hot spare.

To make it a global hot spare, just add it without any extra options:

```
storcli /c0/e252/s7 add hotsparedrive
```

To dedicate it to a drive group, also specify the drive groups:

```
storcli /c0/e252/s7 add hotsparedrive dgs=0,1
```

This command would assign the disk as hot spare to the disk groups 0 and 1.

To extend an existing RAID 5 array, use this command:

```
storcli /c0/v0 start migrate type=raid5 option=add drives=252:7
```

`/v0` is the volume to which to add the disk. `drives` gives the list of disks to add. The list is comma separated and each item is `EID:Slt` (enclosure ID  and slot), i.e. the value in the first column.